# Python and xml.etree.ElementTree -

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I got a big xml-file with the following structure:

```
<defaults>
   <options>
      <param name="email">email@email.org</param>
      <param name="email">email2@email.org</param>
      <param name="email">email3@email.org</param>
   </options>
</defaults>
```

I use xml.etree.ElementTree as ET Lib with the following code:

```
tree = ET.parse("xml_file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for admin in root.iter("param"):
    mail = admin.text("name")
    print(mail)
```

With the code above I ge the param "classes", I need the content (email) between the param-tags.

Andy ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to run your snippet I get

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Because `.text` is an attribute which holds the "text content" of the node.

```py
for admin in root.iter("param"):
    print(admin.text)
```

generates the expected:

```
email@email.org
email2@email.org
email3@email.org
```

I've no idea what "the param "classes"" would even be, there's no "classes" anywhere in what you provide.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I see my explanation is not good. Ill make a new thread with better wording and details. thank you anyway!

Answer (score -1):

See the code below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
emails = [ele.text for ele in list(list(root)[0])]
print(emails)
```

output

```
['email@email.org', 'email2@email.org', 'email3@email.org']
```